# RedirectMatch backreference fails to return value on certain numbers

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to set up a redirect in my .htaccess which will do the following:

```
Redirect www.example.com/1/ to www.example.com/index.php?id=1
```

I've tried both of the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([1-9]{1,}[0-9]*)/$ http://www.example.com/index.php?id=$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/$ http://www.example/index.php?id=$1
```

(Not both at the same time. One or the other.) The first is the preferred option. Basically I want to only redirect when a number that does not start with a leading zero follows the domain, e.g., www.example.com/5/ or www.example.com/205/ but not www.example.com/08/ nor www.example.com/foo/

Either of these work except in certain cases. For example, www.example.com/8/ fails to match or backreference anything, and I end up with www.example.com/index.php?id= with no value inserted for id. However www.example.com/10/ and www.example.com/7/ work fine. /28/ fails. But /18/ works. (All of those are valid ids; the error appears to be that no value is being inserted in the redirect url from the backreference $1.)

So far, www.example.com/8/ and www.example.com/28/ fail to return any value from the match, using either example above. But every other value, e.g., www.example.com/18/ seem to work fine. (So it's not just 8's!) (Maybe there are more "broken" ones I haven't found yet.)

This is particularly annoying with ^/(.*)/$ - That should return anything within the slashes, right? Yet the backreference fails with 8, 28, and maybe other values I haven't discovered yet, while working perfect with others. I don't understand what's going on. Please help.

EDIT: Further testing shows that regardless of whether the expression uses /?$ or /$ to match the trailing /, or if I omit matching for the closing / altogether, I get the same odd results. Only 8 and 28 so far seem to cause this result, but not 18. All other numbers behave correctly.

Comment: Just use: `RedirectMatch ^/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1` and then test in Chrome dev tool.

Comment: Thank you anubhava, but I'm afraid I still get exactly the same results. In a test tool, the rules are correct, but on the real site the results are incorrect.

Comment: That means you site has some conflicting rule/code